# Can Chirper messages be limited to only relevant messages?

Tags: cities-skylines

The ingame Twitter parody Chirper is quite useful because it points out problems in the city. However, there are also numerous filler messages which appear to have no connection to the gameplay at all, like comments about some kind of space program.

Is there a way to limit Chirper messages to only those messages which are relevant to the game?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, via mods:

- [ChirpFilter](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=407871375&searchtext=chirpfilter) removes non-informative "chirps".
- [ChirpyExterminator](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=405791507) deletes Chirpy from the game.

Outside of modding, there isn't a way to disable Chirpy via game settings.

Comment: Also of note: Using these mods (or any mods) will disable your ability to earn achievements.

Comment: But there is another mod that remove the fact that mods removes achievements.  It makes sense to use it if you just want to use a mod to kill Chirper.
(https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=407055819)